# Are there any cloud engine services solely 'pay per use'?

Tags: engines

I'm looking for a chess cloud engine service where I only have to pay for the time I use.
I thought [chessbase.com](https://www.chessbase.com) provides that, but you have to get a premium membership first (as far as I understand).
[Nextchessmove.com](https://www.nextchessmove.com) and [chessify.me](https://www.chessify.me) require subscription as well.
Is anybody aware of an alternative that just bills per time used?

Comment: You could download an engine and rent cloud CPU/GPU. I know Amazon rents CPU per hour and Google rents GPU but I do not know how they bill.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of them let  you pay zero per use.

Download your own program and you only pay once.

Comment: -1 because the advantage of cloud engines is that the hardware is more powerful.